# assimp undefined reference to Importer Ubuntu OpenGL

Tags: opengl, assimp

```
undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::Importer()'
undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::~Importer()'
```

On Ubuntu, using OpenGL.

Followed these steps

```
    Download assimp

        http://sourceforge.net/projects/assimp/files/assimp-3.1/assimp-3.1.1.zip/download

    Open the archive and extract the assimp folder somewhere

    Open a terminal in the assimp directory

    Type

        ~$ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles'
        ~$ make
        ~$ make install
```

Here is the specific code that is failing

```
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>

//.....
Assimp::Importer importer;
//....
```

Any ideas?

I did not do anything special with the makefile to use Assimp. Didn't see anywhere that I was supposed to.

I have also tried sudo apt-get install on the libassimp-dev package and I have tried a sudo ldconfig. I also tried an include in the makefile. Out of ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved

Found solution in a video

needed -lassimp in makefile